# TCODE to Table mapping

Tags: abap

I am experimenting with BDC.
I am inserting data for TCODE: MM01
I want to find out which tables my BDC inserts data into for TCODE MM01.

In other words, If I have a TCODE MM01. How do I know which all tables this TCODE inserts data into.

I know MM01 enters data into MARA table.

Here is how I am checking for this:
I check table TSTC, and find out that TCODE: MM01 uses program SAPMMG01.
However SAPMMG01 enters data into table RMMG1, not MARA as expected.
Here are the screenshots.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know which tables are involved in this process I recommend that you use transaction 'ST05' to trace the transaction and then run 'MM01' and save your material. Then stop the trace and check what happened. With that information you can be sure what tables are involved in this process.

Check [this link](http://scn.sap.com/community/abap/testing-and-troubleshooting/blog/2007/09/05/the-sql-trace-st05-quick-and-easy) regarding on transaction ST05 for more information.

BDC is a high level abstraction used in SAP to record the steps to automate programs, so, at this level you are more likely to see the GUI elements and structures that are used to achieve the task.

By the way, 'RMMG1' is an structure and not a table.

Hope it helps.